# push items into array and return them in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to take an array of numbers and log what numbers are modulus 2 with a remainder of 0 `i % 2 === 0`. For the numbers that are modulus 2 with a remainder of 1 `i % 2 === 1`, I want to push those numbers to an array (seemed like the best fit to log a set of numbers).

From there I would return the sumTotal of the numbers that are `%2 === 0` and print which numbers in the array were `%2 === 1`.

The problem below works for the `if statement` but when I added in my `else if` I am having trouble figuring out how to push items into the array in the else if statement.

```
var numSet = [1, 4, 6, 450, 5, 222, 397, 962, 678, 222, 459];

var myFunc = function (num) {
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i += 1) {
        if (num[i] % 2 === 0) {
            total += num[i];
        } else if (num[i] % 2 === 1) {
            total2[num[i]] = num[i].push;
       console.log(total2);
        }   
    } 
    return 'The total is ' + total + ' and the remainder is ' + total2;
};
```

Comment: The line you want is `total2.push(num[i])`

Comment: @tymeJV that worked, thanks. How would I add in a space between each number when it runs the return statement? as now each number has a comma but no space so its not as clean to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, you can push the new values into `total2` like this

```
total2.push(num[i]);
```

But you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like this

```
var numSet = [1, 4, 6, 450, 5, 222, 397, 962, 678, 222, 459];

var oddNumbers = numSet.filter(function(currentNumber) {
    return currentNumber % 2 === 1;
});

var total = numSet.reduce(function (total, currentNumber) {
    if (currentNumber % 2 === 0) {
        total += currentNumber;
    }
    return total;
}, 0);

console.log(total, oddNumbers);
```

**Output**

```
2544 [ 1, 5, 397, 459 ]
```

Comment: It should be noted that Array.filter and Array.reduce do not work in IE8 and below. I also believe he wanted the array to contain the odd numbers and the total of the even numbers.

Comment: why cant I push the way @tymeJV said? I tried it and it worked. Guessing something bigger may be going on that I am missing.

Comment: @jstone That was my first suggestion too... :)

Comment: Ah gotcha now. Thanks for the clarification.